# Set QT base directory through system variable

Tags: c++, qt, path

I've compiled QT and copied it over to a network drive. But now I've got the problem that the platform plugins are only found on my computer because it seems that those path got compiled into the binaries. How can I make QT to look into another directory? I thought that the system variable `QTDIR` should work but it gets ignored completely. Also tried to add a bunch of directories to the `PATH` variable which didn't work either.

I need a solution which is useable without changing the code itself.

Comment: What are the platform plugins? shared libraries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to load Qt plugins from different path you must use environment variable `QT_PLUGIN_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Qt also looks for the plugins in directories relative to the path where the *executable* is installed. You need to properly deploy your applications, and you definitely don't need to copy the entirety of Qt anywhere. You also don't need to set `QT_PLUGIN_PATH` - it's a workaround for a simple problem.

Ideally, as part of your application's release build process you should be creating an installer, and that installer would then handle putting all the plugins into the application's installation folder.

Comment: well my problem case wasn't for final builds. in development the whole third party libraries are located on a network drive where everyone can use it. for installs all binaries are copied together like you suggested